# Show and hide content in email body (outlook 2010)

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, show-hide

we like to expand and collapse some content in a email body. (show/hide or toggle)

We tried using **CSS-Tags** and **DIVs** to do this. But the Outlook HTML/CSS Rendering Engine seems not to support 'display:none / display:block' and 'onclick' CSS-Tags.

Any chance to do something like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try visibility:hidden

Comment: are you certain that everyone receiving these emails will have outlook 2010? I can see you knowing this if the email gets sent out in like a company newsletter or something to that effect.

Comment: yes, also already tried it with 'visibility' and it´s also not working.

Yes, I can be sure that everyone have Outlook 2010 because we use this only internal in our company for a workflow

Answer (score 0):

Onclick isn't a CSS tag. And you won't be able tu put some javascript in an email.

To display emails, you need to handle your content with tables not with divs to allow most users to see it properly.

Comment: The DIVs are working correct. Just the toggle function is not working because it seems not supported... Thats the reason why I am asking for a different way ;)